# Modify date in fullcalendar.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

In my system I am using the plugins full calendar. For some reason at the time of listing my events, this marks me a day before the actual date. This problem is in all versions. Is it possible to modify this property?

Comment: Can you provide an example which demonstrates your problem?

Comment: @MitBhatt The problem is that when I show my events in full calendar, all that works well, but for example I have an event with start date 2017-02-10 and end date 2017-02-14, full calendar marks me alone Until 2012-02-13. One day less, I want to know if that is something I have to configure in the plugin?

Comment: Try setting the timezone of the full calendar. May be its utc in your db or front end or vice versa. https://fullcalendar.io/docs/timezone/timezone/.

Comment: are these all-day events? Or do they have times as well?

Answer (score 2):

I had this exact problem:

Check the docs here: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/Event_Object/

The `end` property:

> The exclusive date/time an event ends. Optional.
>
> A Moment-ish input, like an ISO8601 string. Throughout the API this
>   will become a real Moment object.
>
> It is the moment immediately after the event has ended. For example,
>   if the last full day of an event is Thursday, the exclusive end of the
>   event will be 00:00:00 on Friday!

It's a little tricky to decipher, but I found that it basically means the end date of an event is excluded.

To work around this I added an extra day to any event that spanned multiple days. You can add this in the [`eventDataTransform` property](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/eventDataTransform/)

```
eventDataTransform: function(eData){
            if( ! eData.end || ! eData.start || eData.className == 'fc-nonbusiness'){
                return eData;
            }

            eData.start = moment(eData.start).utc();
            eData.end = moment(eData.end).utc();

            if (eData.start != eData.end) { //Add a day because full day events exclude the end day by default
                eData.end.add(1, 'days');
            }
            return eData;
        },
```

That's just the bit from my code that I wrote a year ago. You may have to tweak it to work exactly right for you.